# How can i connect 2 PC with different subnets in 1 Switch in 1 Router

Tags: switch, subnet, packet

Well here is the problem...I want to connect 2 PC

```
pc_1: 10.1.1.18/29                 
pc_2: 10.1.1.66/29
```

with 1 switch

```
pc_1 -> Switch Fa0/1
pc_2 -> Switch Fa0/2
```

and this switch to a router

```
router Fa0/0 -> Switch Fa0/3
```

Because pc_1 and pc_2 uses 2 different subnets i cant connect them together.At the router i have lets say the IP address 10.1.1.65 at the Fa0/0 but that way i can only send messages from pc_2.And when i try 10.1.1.17 it only sends messages from pc_1.I made all the appropriate Static Routing and i think the VLAN 'things'..though i think that something has to be done with VLAN Database with the access and trunk registers..if anyone knows it would be really helpfull thank you :)

Comment: read up ccna 1-4

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to setup static routes for the other server via the server's IP address on each server.  This should route internally in the router and bypass the switch.  There are several ways the switch can block traffic between these servers. VLANs do come to mind.

If the servers or router use VLAN tagging, the router may not pass the traffic.  Packet sniffing at one server while trying to ping from the other may help get things up.